# Move UI RectTransform to world position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas

I have a GameObject named *Player*, and a Canvas. The *HealthBar* GameObject is a child of the Canvas *(Canvas>HealthBar)*. I have the HP bar following the player with a script. It is supposed to follow the player at a fixed position above it, so it sits near the top of the sprite.
Here is the 'follow' part of the HP Follow Script.

```
        void Update () 
{
    Vector3 currentPos = transform.position;
    Vector3 playerPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint (Player.transform.position);
    transform.position = playerPos;
```

The problem is that the HP bar moves with the character, but at a very small fraction of the speed of which the player is moving. For example, if the player moves one unit, the bar moves 0.1 units.

Video of error: https://streamable.com/vaz7h

Comment: The script above is attached to the HP Bar. I want it to follow the Player variable, which references the Player GameObject. I made sure the Canvas was not a child of any object.

Comment: I moved the canvas out of the player. It is now its own. It is not any object's child anymore.

Comment: It is a GameObject, but has a UI.Image component attached to it.

Comment: Sure thing. https://streamable.com/vaz7h

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to make a UI Object(Image) follow a GameObject is a SpriteRenderer or MeshRenderer.

In another way, this can be described as converting world point to UI point.

This simple function below converts world position to UI space. It takes a the `Canvas` of the UI as parameter then the position you want to convert to UI position which in your case is the `Player.transform.position` variable.

The key for moving a UI object is the  [`RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html) function which converts the screen point to ui rectangle local point.

```
public Vector3 worldToUISpace(Canvas parentCanvas, Vector3 worldPos)
{
    //Convert the world for screen point so that it can be used with ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle function
    Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPos);
    Vector2 movePos;

    //Convert the screenpoint to ui rectangle local point
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, screenPos, parentCanvas.worldCamera, out movePos);
    //Convert the local point to world point
    return parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public GameObject Player;
public Canvas canvas;
void Update()
{
    //Convert the player's position to the UI space then apply the offset
    transform.position = worldToUISpace(canvas, Player.transform.position);
}
```

---

Now, let's say that you have already positioned the UI to be where it is supposed to be and you now want it to follow another Object(Player), you need to implement a simple offset with the code above. This is really easy. Below is what it is supposed to look like:

```
public GameObject Player;
public Canvas canvas;


Vector3 Offset = Vector3.zero;

void Start()
{
    Offset = transform.position - worldToUISpace(canvas, Player.transform.position);
}

void Update()
{
    //Convert the player's position to the UI space then apply the offset
    transform.position = worldToUISpace(canvas, Player.transform.position) + Offset;
}

public Vector3 worldToUISpace(Canvas parentCanvas, Vector3 worldPos)
{
    //Convert the world for screen point so that it can be used with ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle function
    Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPos);
    Vector2 movePos;

    //Convert the screenpoint to ui rectangle local point
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, screenPos, parentCanvas.worldCamera, out movePos);
    //Convert the local point to world point
    return parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly :) I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you! It's working well if "UI Scale Mode" is set to "Constant Pixel Size". Do you have any ideas how to get it to work if "UI Scale Mode" is set to "Scale With Screen Size"?

Answer (score 1):

If the canvas is ScreenSpace, you can use:

```
healthbarTransform.position = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(playerTransform.position);
```

(if it is screen space, it can be child of player or whatever as long as you set the position every frame)

.... About your problem, there are some factors that will solve the issue:
You are setting the healthbar position in the update function, to let unity know to execute this code after player moves for sure, you need to add HPFollow script to below Default time in the script execution order (if you want to use Update).
Or you can use lateUpdate to set the ui positions. which I highly recommend.

If your problem is just flickering ui, it should be about ui rect transform scales...

Comment: I think a good idea for this issue is to make the HP bar just a child of the Player, but it needs canvas to display the image component, which fills/unfills the bar, because none of these solutions functioned properly, I just continued having the same problem.

Comment: putting the hp bar under player solves nothing besides it is just the same thing as you did in your code. I am pretty sure this is just an execution order problem...

Comment: I changed the execution order to -100 for the HPController script and it didn't affect anything.

Comment: it should be 100 not -100 to unity to set position after player moves by the way... 
and you can just replace Update with LateUpdate...

Comment: Replacing update with lateupdate did nothing. Still the problem remains.

Comment: well after watching your video, it seems that my answer is not your solution. I got you totally wrong...

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help :)

Answer (score -2):

**Here's the solution:**

```
void Start () {
    Canvas.willRenderCanvases += canvasUpdate;
}

void canvasUpdate () {
    var screenPoint = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint( canvas.worldCamera, worldPoint );
    Vector2 localPoint;
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle( canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), screenPoint, canvas.worldCamera, out localPoint );
    transform.localPosition = localPoint;
}
```